# Clarification of doubt

Tags: fiqh, talaq

This is my wife's third marriage and my second. She does not have any children from all her marriages. I am her third husband I recently found out she has been in contact with second ex husband is this allowed because now I don't trust her is it grounds for talaq

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry you are going through this. Have you tried to talk to her about it and let her know that it makes you uncomfortable? Talaq is very, very serious. I think it is better for both of you to be completely open about your opinions on the issue and then decide whether you want to go forward in your marriage or not. I hope everything works out for you inshallah.